# Sql throws 'DBError: ORA-00936: missing expression' when empty expression_list is passed

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running a query similar to:

```
SELECT
  .....
FROM 
  .....
WHERE
  user_id in list;
```

It works fine when the list has some items in it but throws:

> DBError: ORA-00936: missing expression
>   if the list is empty.

Documentation does not tell much: [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm]

Any help on why it does not accept empty list would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is `list` ?

Comment: Nothing specific to `IN`. You can't pass empty lists to almost anything: `SELECT FROM`, `WHERE`, etc. What's your exact problem?

Comment: Say something like: select ... from ... where 1 in [ ]. Don't worry about it, @cableload's answer makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is empty then your query is getting evaluated like this

```
  SELECT
  .....
  FROM 
  .....
  WHERE
  user_id in
```

which results in the missing expression.

So you may want to execute the query if the list is not empty.
If you want the data if the list is empty, you may need to use something like this

```
   SELECT
   .....
   FROM 
   .....
   WHERE
   user_id is null
```